# JUnit test failed to launch

Tags: java, android, eclipse, testing, junit

I am doing my first JUnit test project but its not working.

I did two methods two test.

my console is giving me message " Failed to launch test" !

How can I solve it ?

```
package test;

public class Junit {

    public String concentrate (String one, String two) { 
        return one + two;
    }

    public int multiply (int number1, int number2 ) {
        return number1*number2;
    }
}
```

Test cases:

```
package test;

import junit.framework.TestSuite;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ ConcateTest.class, MultiplyTest.class })
public class AllTests extends TestSuite {

}
```

Multiply test:

```
package test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class MultiplyTest {

    @Test
    public void testMultiply() {
        Junit test = new Junit();
        int result = test.multiply(3, 4);
        assertEquals(12, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the JUnit test case class and also explain the steps you took to run the test case? Please?

Comment: @bot I have added the class to the question now. I tried running it on my android device - run as Junit android application. whatever I do I still get the same error and it does not launch (

Comment: Your `AllTests` class shouldn't extend `TestSuite`. If you are writing JUnit4-style tests (i.e. tests that use the `@Test` annotation) then you shouldn't import any code from `junit.framework`

Answer (score -1):

you have no methods annotated with `@Test` . Try to add a method annotated with `@Test` like :

```
@Test
public void test(){
   Assert.assertTrue(multiply(2, 2) == 4);
}
```

cause in your actual code you test nothing

Comment: I have added test case @agonist  public class MultiplyTest  {@Test
 public void testMultiply() {
  
  Junit test = new Junit();
  int result = test.multiply(3, 4);
  assertEquals(12, result);